# Fluent NHibernate "could not resolve property" on lambda expression

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda, fluent-nhibernate, expression

I'm using Fluent NHibernate and mapping by conventions only, and these are the classes I'm trying to select:

```
//The attributes are used in my conventions
[Table("Entries")]
public class Entry
{
    [Id] public virtual int EntryID { get; set; }
    [Join("UserID", Join.Left)] public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Id] public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My select function is this:

```
public IList<T> GetBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class
{
    ISession session = _dal.GetSession(typeof(T));
    ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<T>();

    //Error: could not resolve property "User.Name"
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Where<T>(expression));

    return criteria.List<T>();
}
```

And I'm calling with this expression:

```
IList<Entry> entries = Repository.GetBy<Entry>(e => e.User.Name == "Myself");
```

The code above works for expressions' members belonging to the root class, but not if it involves any of it's class properties, and my question is, is there anyway I can do the code above work in a simple way? (without having to parse the expression myself).

Comment: You will need to create a projection of "User" so you can do `u.Name == ""Myself`. The criteria won't resolve a second level of indirection (e.User.Name) so far I remember.

Answer (score 0):

As @Claudio Redi comment, criteria will not resolve a second level of indirection (e.User.Name). You could use LINQ to resolve this problem, for sample:

```
public IList<T> GetBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class
{
    ISession session = _dal.GetSession(typeof(T));

    var query = session.Query<T>().Where(expression);

    return query.ToList();
}
```